# How to use DB router in Django 1.4

Tags: python, django, multiple-databases

I've been trying to setup Django 1.4.3 to use multiple DBs, but for the life of me I can't make it to work. I read the documentation and posts on SO, and did the following:

**1)** Add a second DB configuration in `settings.py`, as follows:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': '/tmp/django.db',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    },
    'db1' : {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'db1',
        'USER': 'fake',
        'PASSWORD': 'fake',
        'HOST': 'fake.host.com',
        'PORT': '3306',
    },
}
```

**2)** Create a `routers.py` and define a DB router as follows
(Note: According to SO posts, if you define a DB router in `models.py`, the router will not work)

```
class DBRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        return 'db1'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        return 'db1'

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        return 'db1'
```

**3)** Add the following lines to `settings.py`
(Note: According to SO posts, these lines must be AFTER the `DATABASES` configurations

```
from django.db import connections
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['fakeproject.routers.DBRouter',]
```

**This was wrong. Do NOT put `from django.db import connections` here as it prevents the router to be registered**

**My symptoms:**
Apparently, all my calls are routed through the default DB. Details below:

- Both DB settings work (I can perform `manage.py indpectdb --database db1` successfully
- `DATABASE_ROUTERS` setting does not generate any complains (even if I put a wrong path to the DB router, or even a non-string object)
- When I attempt to access my objects via `manage.py shell`, I can do `MyModel.objects.all()` but when I actually try to iterate it, I'm told `no such table`. The default DB does not have that table, but 'db1' clearly has it as I generated the model by using `inspectdb` on it. As a proof, if I swap the DB configuration between `db1` and `default`, I can access the object without problems.

Any help highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out that the statement in step 3 "`from django.db import connections`
" was preventing the DB router to be registered. When I removed this statement, the router was registered and stuff started to work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is probably arising because your `routers.py` only returns a reference to `'db1'` but as you say you're only being routed to `'default'` I'm unsure (I would expect it to be the only routed to `'db1'`.

In `routers.py` create a master router class, and then subclass for each DB - and initialise with an `app_label` string so you can set them apart.

```
class MasterRouter(object):
    def __init__(self, app_label):
        super(MasterRouter, self).__init__()
        self.app_label = app_label

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == self.app_label:
            return self.app_label
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label == self.app_label:
            return self.app_label
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label == self.app_label or obj2._meta.app_label == self.app_label:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        if db == 'default':
            return model._meta.app_label == self.app_label
        elif model._meta.app_label == self.app_label:
            return False
        return None

class DefaultRouter(MasterRouter):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DefaultRouter, self).__init__('default')

class DB1Router(MasterRouter):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DB1Router, self).__init__('db1')
```

and then in your `settings.py` declare the routers

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = [ 'routers.DefaultRouter', 'routers.DB1Router' ]
```

ofcourse, you'll probably want to set up your `MasterRouter` class overrides differently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Why would having a subclass in between solve the problem though?

Comment: You need two classes in `DATABASE_ROUTERS` - one for each DB. I'm subclassing as I prefer DRY code (you could rewrite as two classes, but the code would be near identical).