# How to gracefully handle OperationalError 2003 and change database with .using()

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x

Suppose you have a Django 1.11 app, `the-app` on site `the-site`.

In `the-site/settings.py` you have the following databases:

```
DATABASES = {                                                                   
 'default': {                                                                
     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',                                   
     'NAME': 'the-site_webapp',                                                   
     'USER': 'tester',                                                       
     'PASSWORD': '',                                                         
     'HOST': 'localhost',                                                    
     'PORT': '3306',                                                                                                
 },                                                                          
 'remote-db1': {                                                                
     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',                                   
     'NAME': 'remote-db1',                                                      
     'USER': 'tester',                                                       
     'PASSWORD': '',                                                
     'HOST': '<ip1>',    
     'PORT': '3306',                                      
 },
 'remote-db2': {                                                                
     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',                                   
     'NAME': 'remote-db2',                                                      
     'USER': 'tester',                                                       
     'PASSWORD': '',                                                
     'HOST': '<ip2>',    
     'PORT': '3306',                                      
 },
}
```

where `remote-db2` contains a restricted subset of `remote-db1` and can therefore stand in it's stead.

There is also the following router information:

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = [ 'the-app.routers.DefaultRouter', 'the-app.routers.the-appRouter',]
```

Pointing to `the-app/routers.py`:

```
class MasterRouter(object):                                                                                            
 '''                                                                         
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13988432/how-to-use-db-router-in-django-1-4
 '''                                                                         
 def __init__(self, app_label, db_name):                                     
     super(MasterRouter, self).__init__()                                    
     self.app_label = app_label                                              
     self.db_name = db_name                                                  


 def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):                                      
     if model._meta.app_label == self.app_label:                             
         return self.db_name                                                 
         #return self.app_label                                              
     return None                                                             

 def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):                                     
     if model._meta.app_label == self.app_label:                             
         return self.db_name                                                 

     return None                                                             

 def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):                              
     if obj1._meta.app_label == self.app_label or obj2._meta.app_label == self.app_label:
         return True                                                         
     return None                                                             

 def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):                                          
     if db == 'default':                                                     
         return model._meta.app_label == self.app_label                      
     elif model._meta.app_label == self.app_label:                           
         return False                                                        
     return None                                                             

 def allow_migrate(self, db, *args, **kwargs):                               
     if db in ['remote-db1']:                                            
         return False     


class DefaultRouter(MasterRouter):                                              
 def __init__(self):                                                         
     super(DefaultRouter, self).__init__('default', 'default')               

class the-appRouter(MasterRouter):                                                  
 def __init__(self):                                                                                       
     super(the-appRouter, self).__init__('the-app', 'remote-db1')
```

In `the-app/views.py`, you have:

```
def foo (request):
    try:              
     curfile = ModelName.objects.get(**arg_dict)                            
     return _fetch_info(request, curfile)                                    
    except (KeyError, ModelName.DoesNotExist) as e:       
         messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Couldn\'t find sample in remote-db1; attempting to connect to remote-db2')
         try:                                                                    
             curfile = ModelName.objects.using('remote-db2').get(**arg_dict)       
             return _fetch_info(request, curfile)                                
         except (KeyError, ModelName.DoesNotExist) as e:                        
             messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Couldn\'t fetch sample data.')
             return render(request, 'foo.html')                            
         except (OperationalError,) as e:                                        
             messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Couldn\'t connect to remote-db2.')
             traceback.print_exc() # debugging                                   
             return render(request, 'invalid.html')                              
     except (OperationalError) as e:                                             
          messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Couldn\'t connect to remote-db1. Trying remote-db2.')
          traceback.print_exc() # debugging                                       
          try:                                                                    
             curfile = ModelName.objects.using('remote-db2').get(**arg_dict)       
             return _fetch_info(request, curfile)                                
          except (KeyError, SampleFile.DoesNotExist) as e:                          
              messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Couldn\'t fetch sample data.')
              return render(request, 'view_info.html')                            
          except (OperationalError,) as e:                                        
              messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, 'Couldn\'t connect to either remote-db1 nor to remote-db2.')
              traceback.print_exc() # debugging                                   
              return render(request, 'invalid.html')
```

Looking at the `traceback` logs, what appears to happen is that despite my telling Django with `.using('remote-db2')` to connect to `remote-db2`, it attempts *again* to connect to `remote-db1`.

Is there somewhere on my end that I can handle this OperationalError (code 2003)? It [looks like](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/backends/base/base.py) (line 205) this might not be possible ([ever](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14717)), but there must be some way to gracefully handle this in some way other than rendering an error page saying "try again later"!

Thank you so much for your time reading and for any help you can give me :)

EDIT: I do not manage the legacy db nor the new db, so I cannot easily implement any sort of load-balancing or failover strategy on the db side. I was directed to django-failover: github.com/brianjaystanley/django-failover (sorry, can't do more than 2 links in a post due to n00b status), but I am using python 3.5 and would have to update the package, if it's still applicable to Django 1.11! Furthermore, the schema are slightly different for the two remote db's, despite them containing information about the same objects, so django-failover would not be applicable.

Related posts:

1. stackoverflow.com/questions/18174910/django-database-routers-failover-scenario
2. stackoverflow.com/questions/28554740/in-django-1-6-handle-mysql-failover-while-using-database-routers

(I read others before making this post, but the problems were to do with misconfiguration of [Django pointing to MySQL db at localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11121819/mysqldb-in-python-cant-connect-to-mysql-server-on-localhost))

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why not one single database?

Comment: I'm having to operate over a legacy database as well as a newer database; the legacy database, <code>remote_db1</code>, contains a whole bunch of tables that are no longer needed for most processes, and due to the sheer number of records, is very difficult to search. The newer database, <code>remote_db2</code>, contains a truncation of the data in <code>remote_db1</code> (only 1 month back), as well as a subset of the original tables. There are also some small changes made to the schema of some of the tables. But if something happens to the legacy db, then I want to failover to the new db.